# Migrate forms from EE2 Freeform to Craft 3 Freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform, migration, import, freeform, export

I need to migrate some forms from Freeform in ExpressionEngine 2 to Freeform in Craft 3. Do you know of any tools or methods that exist that can help me out with this? Or am I doomed to do this manually?